# Where clause with multiple conditions in SQL DB2

Tags: sql, db2

```
Col1    Col2        Col3

ABC     Product     Digital
ABC     SubProduct  XF
BCD     Product     Non-Digital
BCD     SubProduct  <White Space>
CDE     Product     Digital
CDE     SubProduct  Null
DEF     Product     Non-Digital
DEF     SubProduct  FR
```

Desired Output:

```
Col1    Product         SubProduct

ABC     Digital         XF
DEF     Non-Digital     FR
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
WHERE (Col2 IN ('Product','SubProduct') AND NOT Col3 LIKE '')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you mean `select * from table where col2 in ('Product','SubProduct) and Col3 <> ''  ` ? (assumes Col3 is NOT NULL, else use `coalesce(Col3,'') <> '' `

Comment: @mao - Tried this but I'm seeing the product as Null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH TAB (Col1, Col2, Col3) AS
(
VALUES
  ('ABC', 'Product', 'Digital')
, ('ABC', 'SubProduct', 'XF')
, ('BCD', 'Product', 'Non-Digital')
, ('BCD', 'SubProduct', ' ')
, ('CDE', 'Product', 'Digital')
, ('CDE', 'SubProduct', Null)
, ('DEF', 'Product', 'Non-Digital')
, ('DEF', 'SubProduct', 'FR')
)
SELECT A.Col1, A.Col3 AS Product, B.Col3 AS SubProduct
FROM TAB A
JOIN TAB B ON B.Col1 = A.Col1 AND B.Col2 = 'SubProduct'
WHERE A.Col2 = 'Product' AND NULLIF(B.Col3, '') IS NOT NULL;

|COL1|PRODUCT    |SUBPRODUCT |
|----|-----------|-----------|
|ABC |Digital    |XF         |
|DEF |Non-Digital|FR         |
```

[dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=3d9c9701f712459c13c96c34919ae5df)

Comment: @Chris Run this **as is**. It returns the result set provided on my Db2 11.1. I've added a dbfiddle example as well. If you still get an empty result set, then what’s you Db2 version and platform?

Comment: thanks this worked fine now. I also see some times the Product has 'Null' values, in that case I want Product column as null in the output.

Comment: There is no `Product` column in the source table. There are `ColX` columns. What does it mean: "Product has 'Null' values"? Is this `NULL` value in `Col3` where `Col2='Product'`?

Comment: @ MarkBrainstein, Never mind, I got that working as expected, Thank you.